# OSError: mysql_config not found

Tags: python, mysql, django

I tried installing mysqlclient on python today but it gets all messy and gives me this error

```
***raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found*** then I tried to edit the mysql.config file by adding 
***#Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"***
```

but still it gives me the same error. I am on mac version 10.6.8.
The details of the error are:

```
****Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

File "/private/var/folders/s4/s4O4m-85EgGDXYYsUzcvNU+++TQ/-Tmp-/pip-
build-s7w0agk6/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>

metadata, options = get_config()

File "/private/var/folders/s4/s4O4m-85EgGDXYYsUzcvNU+++TQ/-Tmp-/pip-
build-s7w0agk6/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config

libs = mysql_config("libs_r")

File "/private/var/folders/s4/s4O4m-85EgGDXYYsUzcvNU+++TQ/-Tmp-/pip-
build-s7w0agk6/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config

raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))

OSError: mysql_config not found****
```

I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: python mysql in mariadb-devel, please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922955/installing-mysql-python-without-mysql-server-on-centos)

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the path via terminal:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

to make it permanent add it to to end of `/etc/paths` file.